# .htaccess url rewrite for ssl https redirection

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, ssl, https

I've used different codes provided here on other questions' solutions and on the internet. I'm really not savvy with `htaccess`. Bought and confirmed working SSL Certificate, but I'm new to applying these redirects.

**Goal:**
*I need to rewrite http to https on the following directories.*

- http://mydomain.com/products-page/checkout
- http://mydomain.com/products-page/your-account
- http://mydomain.com/wp-login

I'm on shared hosting via Dreamhost. I have a dedicated IP, if that helps.

Initial code I was using recommended to me by a Dreamhost representative:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} wp-login 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/wp-login/$1 [R,L]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try these rules in the htaccess file in your document root.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/wp-login|/products-page/checkout|/products-page/your-account)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://mydomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

The first condition checks if the request isn't HTTPS, the second checks if the request starts with either `/wp-login`, `/products-page/checkout`, or `/products-page/your-account`, and if both apply, then the rewrite simply takes the entire URI and redirects to https://.

Comment: Nevermind, I got it to work, thanks! (I didn't put it at the root/top lines. Derp!)