# URL redirection using ELB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

My application's URL is: abc.com. I have configured SSL in it and I am also using ELB that acts as the proxy server to the application. Now if someone hits www.abc.com, I want it(www.abc.com) to be redirected to abc.com and also SSL should work.

I have added www.abc.com to the DNS. Now www.abc.com is working but SSL is not working for the same.  How can this be done in AWS. Is there any setting in ELB for the same.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need `.htaccess` configs for that.

Comment: What exactly is .htaccess. Could you please let me know how to use that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.htaccess url rewrite for ssl https redirection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11766781/htaccess-url-rewrite-for-ssl-https-redirection)

Comment: I am not using apache so how can I use .htaccess configs

Comment: So what you use than on ElasticBeanstalk?

Comment: I don't use ElasticBeanstalk. My request comes first to ELB(Elastic load balancer) which then forwards it to any one of the two servers(EC2 instances).